# Where can I add $http support to this AngularJS sample (Umbraco)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco

I'm trying to add support for $http.get to my AngularJS controller in Umbraco.

My controller is looking like:

```
angular.module('AddAnswerModule', [])
    .controller('AddAnswerController', AddAnswerController)
```

{

```
function AddAnswerController() {
}

AddAnswerController.prototype.greet = function () {
    alert(this.answer);
    // $http.get("...") - NOT WORKING
};
```

}

I have tried different variants, but can not understand where should I put support for $http . I have seen multiple different forms of declaring controllers, but I want to keep code as simple and separated by functions as this (no fabric with long chain of calling from controller declaration).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency like this :

```
function MyController($http) {

}
```

I suggest you to have a look at Angular Best Practices from here :

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Not working. If I add it like:
function AddAnswerController($http) {   }

    AddAnswerController.prototype.greet = function ($http) { }
it still does not support this request.

Comment: Which error do you get ? and you don't have to put $http in the greet function !

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at AddAnswerController.greet  - seems that it does not see this function.

Comment: I have no knowledge on Umbraco and how it is implemented with Angular, but I find it weird you have AddAnswerController.prototype.greet

What is "prototype" for ? 

The error shows from 'AddAnswerController.greet' and not 'AddAnswerController.prototype.greet'

And where are you calling this function 'greet' ?